# Parsing a factor string in R

Tags: r, factors

I have a  string ,

```
x = "[1,2,3]"
```

How can I get the elements 1 and 2 from the string?

I tried the strsplit but that seems a bit tricky. Then I tried splitting on "[", and that also did not seem easy.

Comment: How did you wind up with such a string? Are you parsing a JSON object perchance? There are packages for R that would make that easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `regex` lookaround to extract the numbers

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, '(?<=\\[|,)\\d+(?=,)')[[1]]
#[1] "1" "2"
```

Comment: is there something up with my rstudio or os? When I copy your code I get `Error in gregexpr("(?<=\\[|,)\\...
  invalid regular expression '(?<=\[|,)\d+(?=,)', reason 'Invalid regexp'`

Comment: @plafort In the previous `stringr` edition, you may need to wrap it with `perl`, which is no longer needed. ie. `str_extract_all(x, perl('(?<=\\[|,)\\d+(?=,)'))[[1]]`

Comment: `str_extract_all(x, "(?<=\\[|,)\\d+(?=,)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
Error ...
  unused argument (perl = TRUE)` did I wrap it correctly?

Comment: @plafort I edited the previous comment.  Can you try that code

Comment: yes it worked. thank you. Is there a new stringr that I should look for?

Comment: @plafort You can reinstall the cran version.

Answer (score 1):

A base option, here we just remove the brackets and split by `,`, though do note @MrFlick's comment.

```
strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", "", x), ",")[[1L]][1:2]
# [1] "1" "2"
```

Comment: You may also do `strsplit(x, '\\D')[[1]][2:3]`

Comment: @akrun, though of something like that, but need to watch out for things like `1.23, 5e-38`, etc.